# Rotations of sphere $\mathbb S^2$

Tags: geometry, lie-groups, spherical-geometry, spheres

- In the picture bellow; How to prove that the result of rotation about $P$ through
  angle $\theta$, followed by rotation about $Q$ through angle $\varphi$ is rotation about $R$ through some angle? ــ Can it be proven by the reflections of the great circles $\mathscr{L,M,N}$? How?
- How to find the axis of the product rotation?

[image]

Comment: The first rotation is the reflection through $L$ followed by reflection through $M$. For the second, it's $M$ followed by $N$. The $M$'s cancel, and you're left with a rotation with axis $OR$. Your problem gives a great proof that a product of rotations is a rotation, by the way.

Comment: How do we know that a rotation is two reflections?

Comment: Say you have a composite of two reflections with respect to intersecting planes making an angle $\alpha$. Call their line of intersection $a$. Draw any plane perpendicular to $a$, and let $b$ and $c$ be the lines of intersection of that plane with the first two. Lines $b$ and $c$ make an angle $\alpha$. Check that the effect of the two reflections *within that plane* is a reflection through $b$ followed by a reflection through $c$. That yields a rotation with angle $2 \alpha$.

Comment: @David I'd say your two comments together make an answer here. Would you care to post it as such?

Answer (score 2):

The first rotation is the reflection through $L$ followed by reflection through $M$. For the second, it's $M$ followed by $N$. The $M$'s cancel, and you're left with a rotation with axis $OR$.